# MUnit coverage report of Mule in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mule

We are using the MUnit plugin for our code coverage of our mule application. Is there a way to integrate this plugin in Jenkins?
We searched for a MUnit plugin in Jenkins but this did not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MUnit plugin for code coverage publishes the coverage in `\target\munit-reports\coverage` folder. You publish this report in Jenkins. But make sure you have html reports enabled in pom file.

```
<coverage>
    <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
    <formats>
        <format>console</format>
        <format>html</format>
    </formats>
</coverage>
```

Then make use of **HTML Publisher Plugin** and configure post build job as

[image]

Once executed you can see code coverage in project dashboard.

Hope this helps.